# Jquery Checkbox filter on new page

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, filter

I am currently building a website with a large list that will be identified with a number of tags each.
Im trying to create a checkbox list on the main page that depending on what boxes the user selects will bring up the results on a new page.
Each checkbox will have a specific tag and each result can have multiple tags attached.
If tried all the other checkbox filters on this site but since my list has hundreds of items none of them will work or they show on the main page and spill over the borders of the sites design.

Has anyone seen a code that could assist me.

My best example of what im trying to do is this site [here.](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/search/genre)

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Put the 'tags' on the querystring and retrive them in the next page.

```
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="category" value="Drama" /><label  for="cb1">Drama</label><br />
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" name="category" value="Horror"/><label  for="cb2">Horror</label><br />
<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" name="category" value="Comedy"/><label  for="cb3">Comedy</label><br />
<input id="cb4" type="checkbox" name="category" value="Action"/><label  for="cb4">Action</label><br />     

<script type="text/javascript">
    search = function () {
        var categories = new Array();
        $.each($("input[name='category']:checked"), function () {
            categories.push($(this).val());
        });     
        window.location.href = "./search?category=" + categories;
    }       
</script>
```